# how to update GUI with button click

Tags: php

I'm making a web application how i can add update button in admin panel
update button to replace the GUI or Replace the whole html file
Example

```
<?php
if ( admin clicked  update button) !== false) {
    Replace login.html with https://github.com/new-version

}
```

can anybody help me with this idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Do this in the HTML on click when user presses the button

```
   <button onclick="location.href='https://github.com/new-version'">Update</button>
```

Ok sorry try this

```
<?php
 unlink("login.html");
 copy("https://github.com/new-version/login.html", "login.html");
```

Comment: idon't want location iwant  to replace it

Comment: Ok could you do something like I have added?